# Javascript ReferenceError while passing path

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

I have a javascript method

```
function addData(path)
{
  //logic here
}
```

and I am calling it as

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData(abc)">
```

This gives me error

```
[01:23:10.432] ReferenceError: abc is not defined @ javascript:addData(abc):1
```

Surprisingly it allows me to do something like

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData(123)">
```

So what should be done here ? I tried doing

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData('abc')">
```

but it gets converted to

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData(&apos;abc&apos;)">
```

and then gives me syntax error

```
[01:29:07.212] SyntaxError: syntax error @ javascript:addData(&apos;abc&apos;):1
```

Using `onclick` instead of `href` also has same effect.

I want to pass a path to the method which would be something like `/package/version/1.0/data`

Comment: “it gets converted”… by what?

Comment: So, you want to pass a string literal.  Enclosing the literal in apostrophes ought to work.  When you say, "it gets converted," where in the process is the conversion happening?

Comment: I am doing "inspect element" and adding the value in browser. As soon as I press enter it gets converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be attaching a click handler or, if you must, use the onclick attribute to call JS functions.

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData(abc)">
```

Doesn't work because `abc` is a variable. It obviously doesn't exist from there.

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData(123)">
```

This works because `123` is an integer(number) literal.

```
<a id="dataSource" title="Add Data" href="javascript:addData('abc')">
```

This string is getting encoded automatically for security reasons. You would need to escape a string literal if you had to pass it in this way. I find I don't need to do anything with onclick and this would work just fine. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/s5Mxz8KPYcUypEkY0qdX?p=preview

This should work just fine:

```
<button id="dataSource" onclick="addData('abc')">Add</button>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: And how do we escape the string?

Comment: @AniketThakur I don't need to escape it with onclick. Does this not work for you? http://plnkr.co/edit/s5Mxz8KPYcUypEkY0qdX?p=preview

Comment: @AniketThakur I edited to add a simple button to help show you want I mean. You don't have to worry about escaping anything if you just use an onclick this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a string then you should do like this:

```
addData(\""+abc+"\")
```

If you want to pass a variable just addData(abc) should be fine.
With numbers, it works because you have no variable named "abc" so it's ok.

I suggest you to do like this:

```
<a href="" onClick="addData(whatdoyouwant)">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing it, is something like this:

```
<a onClick="addData('SomePath')" href="#">Link</a>
```

In other words, use the *onClick* event instead of the *javascript:* urls, and wrap your path using single quotes

[I set up this fiddle for you to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/augustoaltman/ruprmn84/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah all the answer posted are correct but we can do this by using `href` as well.

```
<a href='javascript:addData("${dataPath}")' id='dataPathId' title="${dataTitle}">
```

I did not need any escaping of characters. Though for doing similar thing from the same method again in js I had to something like

```
function addData(path)
{
//logic
dataNode.childNodes[i].href = "javascript:addData(\"" + path + "\")";
//logic
}
```